# StreamBuilder showing data only on hot reload in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, stream-builder

I am facing a problem with Streambuilder.
The workflow of my app is like there is a list of items when I press on add to favorites it adds the item to firestore. Then I am fetching data from firestore using stream and showing it on another screen using stream builder.
The problem is that the stream builder is empty when I hot reload the app the data shows perfectly.
[this is the part where I am calling stream method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Weqy.png)
[this is streambuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWzu9.png)
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: please add your code also for fetching data from firestore.

Comment: I have added some part of code please check the edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the extra variable `resultStream` and directly use the function `DatabaseManager.getUserCurrency()` in your `StreamBuilder` like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
   stream: DatabaseManager.getUserCurrency(context),
   builder: (context, snapshot){...}
)
```

if this does not fix the issue, check your `getUserCurrency()` function for errors. This is an example for getting a `Stream` from Firestore:

```
Stream<UserData> getUserData(String uid) {
  try {
    return userCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) => event?.data() != null ? UserData.fromMap(event.data()) : null);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Additionally you normally don’t have to await a `Stream`, which might cause the issue in your case, because you are calling the async function in your `initState`.

Comment: The very first way worked for me. Instead of using a variable if I directly use the method everything is working fine. Thanks a lot for giving time to resolve issue and give multiple solutions